# Right hand camera to left hand, OpenCV to Unity

Tags: opencv, matrix, unity-game-engine, camera

I have a problem that has been puzling me for the last few days. I have a camera pose obtained with Opencv that is right handed (X-right, Y-up, Z-back) and I would like to visualize in Unity (X-right, Y-up, Z-forward) but I cannot really manage to get it right.

I tried to do it using either quaternions or matrices and it should be just mirroring the Z axis and set the rotation of the transform of the camera in Unity to the computed transformation however I cannot get the right conversion.

With quaternions I tried to mirror by negating the Z and W term and I achieved a coordinate system (X-right, Y-down, Z-forward), it makes sense but it is not what I want to achieve. With matrices I think I should multiply my right hand camera by an identity matrix with the element [2,2] set to -1, however I don't get what I want.

I am definitely missing something, probably something really stupid I forgot :)

Has anybody a suggestion?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenCV rotation (Rodrigues) and translation vectors for positioning 3D object in Unity3D](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36561593/opencv-rotation-rodrigues-and-translation-vectors-for-positioning-3d-object-in)

Answer (score 4):

A Quaternion can be thought of as a rotation around an axis `a = (ax, ay, az)` by an angle `theta`

```
qx = ax * sin(theta/2)
qy = ay * sin(theta/2)
qz = az * sin(theta/2)
qw = cos(theta/2)
```

In a right-handed coordinate system a rotation of `theta` will be counter-clockwise, while in a left-handed coordinate system a rotation of `theta` will be clockwise (depending on your point-of-view, of course).

So to get your quaternion from a right-handed system to Unity's Left-Handed system you have to account for two factors:

1. The Z-Axis is negated
2. The direction of rotation is flipped from CCW to CW

We first factor is accounted for by negating the `qz` component of the quaternion. The second factor is accounted for by flipping the axis of rotation (rotating by 90 degrees around 1,0,0 is the inverse of rotating 90 degrees around -1,0,0).

If your original right-handed quaternion is `q` and your left-handed quaternion is `q'`That means you end up with:

```
q'=(-qx, -qy, qz, qw)
```

### Additional Note

- Quaternions don't inherently have a handedness. A quaterion `q` applies equally well in RH or LH coordinate systems. However, when you apply the quaternion to a spatial vector, the resulting transformation takes on the handedness of the vector's space.

Comment: Thanks for the exahustivre explanation, I tried the transformation today but what I got is a coordinate system with X-right, Y-down and Z-back. From this coordinate system I achieve what I want by rotating 180 degrees on the X axis however if I apply more rotations on the Z axis of the object I get inverted rotations.

Comment: It is certainly possible that I got something wrong. The fact that you end up with a rotation that is 180 degrees off makes me think that the openCV camera's rotation may be given in a coordinate system with X-Right, Y-Down, and Z-Forward. (See: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iFEV.png) That would put the look direction of the open-cv camera facing 180 degrees opposite and should change the conversion to `q'=(-qx, qy, -qz, qw)`.