# Rotation conversion between OpenGL and Unity, does rotation order matter?

Tags: unity-game-engine, opengl, graphics, rotation, mo-cap

**Background** :
I'm currently dealing with motion capture data with .bvh format. 
.bvh contains the bones length and animation data (each bones' rotation angles (Z-Y-X) on every frame)
I implemented the .bvh bones and animation in OpenGL. The rotations in .bvh is in Z-Y-X order. 
Now I want load this .bvh to Unity engine and apply the bones' rotation to my 3D character. (like a animation retargeting)

**What I knew** : OpenGL coordinate system uses right-hand rule, and Unity uses left-hand rule. 
If I want to translate a axis-angle form rotation **(x,y,z, angle)** from OpenGL to Unity. It should be **(-x,y,z,-angle)**.
for quaternion , it would be **OpenGL (x,y,z,w)**   ->   **Unity (x,-y,-z,w)**

**My question is**: .bvh uses Z-Y-X rotation order, and Unity uses Z-X-Y rotation order.
Does the rotation order also need to be considered during the translation ?

Comment: Here is the [image](https://prnt.sc/BXeNUxvkd53Z) of the coordinate system

Comment: Afaik the quaternion would rather be `(-x, -y, z, w)` .. see similar/duplicate questions like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41816497/right-hand-camera-to-left-hand-opencv-to-unity) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263072/changing-a-matrix-from-right-handed-to-left-handed-coordinate-system)